GridDB setup failing with Go client
I'm encountering an error when trying to run a sample file after installing GridDB on Ubuntu with the Go client. Here are the details of my setup:

GridDB version: 5.5.1

Go version: go1.18.1

Operating system: Ubuntu Linux (amd64)


I followed the installation instructions provided in the GridDB documentation for Ubuntu and for installing the Go client.
However, when I attempt to run a sample file, I encounter an error. Here's the error message:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/griddb/go_client"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func generate_data(numSensors int) map[string][][]interface{} {
    containerNameList := make([]string, numSensors)
    for i := range containerNameList {
        containerNameList[i] = "test_sensor_" + strconv.Itoa(i)
    }

    now := time.Now()

    s1 := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r1 := rand.New(s1)

    times := make([][]time.Time, len(containerNameList))
    id := make([][]int, len(containerNameList))
    data := make([][]float64, len(containerNameList))
    temp := make([][]float64, len(containerNameList))

    var inEntryList = make(map[string][][]interface{}, 0)
    fullData := make([][][]interface{}, 1)
    fullData[0] = make([][]interface{}, len(containerNameList))

    for i := 0; i < len(containerNameList); i++ {
        innerLen := numSensors
        fullData[0][i] = make([]interface{}, innerLen)
        times[i] = make([]time.Time, innerLen)
        id[i] = make([]int, innerLen)
        data[i] = make([]float64, innerLen)
        temp[i] = make([]float64, innerLen)

        var rowList []interface{}

        for j := 0; j < innerLen; j++ {
            addedTime := i * 1
            timeToAdd := time.Minute * time.Duration(addedTime)
            incTime := now.Add(timeToAdd)

            times[i][j] = incTime
            id[i][j] = j
            data[i][j] = (r1.Float64() * 100) + float64(numSensors)
            x := (r1.Float64() * 100) + 2
            temp[i][j] = math.Floor(x*100) / 100

            var row []interface{}
            row = append(row, times[i][j])
            row = append(row, id[i][j])
            row = append(row, data[i][j])
            row = append(row, temp[i][j])
            rowList = append(rowList, row)
        }
        fullData[0][i] = rowList
    }

    for _, val := range fullData {
        for i := 0; i < numSensors; i++ {
            rowList := [][]interface{}{}
            idx := containerNameList[i]
            for _, innerVal := range val {
                rowList = append(rowList, innerVal[i].([]interface{}))
            }
            inEntryList[idx] = rowList
        }
    }

    return inEntryList
}

func main() {
    factory := griddb_go.StoreFactoryGetInstance()
    gridstore, err := factory.GetStore(map[string]interface{}{
        "host":         "239.0.0.1",
        "port":         31999,
        "cluster_name": "defaultCluster",
        "username":     "admin",
        "password":     "admin"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failure getting the gridstore: ", err)
        panic("err get store")
    }
    defer griddb_go.DeleteStore(gridstore)

    numSensors := 1
    fullDataset := generate_data(numSensors)

    for containerName := range fullDataset {
        fmt.Println("containerName: ", containerName)
        conInfo, err := griddb_go.CreateContainerInfo(map[string]interface{}{
            "name": "griddb"+containerName,
            "column_info_list": [][]interface{}{
                {"timestamp", griddb_go.TYPE_TIMESTAMP},
                {"id", griddb_go.TYPE_SHORT},
                {"data", griddb_go.TYPE_FLOAT},
                {"temperature", griddb_go.TYPE_FLOAT}},
            "type":    griddb_go.CONTAINER_TIME_SERIES,
            "row_key": true})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR CreateContainerInfo")
        }
        defer griddb_go.DeleteContainerInfo(conInfo)

        _, err = gridstore.PutContainer(conInfo)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR PutContainer, ", err)
        }
    }

    err = gridstore.MultiPut(fullDataset)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error from MultiPut: ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("successfully Put: : ", fullDataset)
    }
}

It gives me the error:
libgridstore.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Despite adhering to all the instructions provided in the documentation, I am still facing this issue. Could anyone provide some insight into why this error is occurring and suggest a possible solution? I appreciate any kind of help!
